# jquery runtime Object state maintain

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am using jquery

```
var message='';

message='<p>Are you sure want to delete ?</p>';
message +='<p style=\'text-align:right;margin: 5px;\'>';                
message +='<span><input type=\'button\' value=\'Yes\' class=\'button\'';
message +='onclick="yesOption(\''+this+'\',\''+requestData+'\',\''+gridObject+'\')" /></span>';
message +='<span><input type=\'button\' value=\'No\' id=\'btnNo\' class=\'button\'';
message +=' onclick="return noOption(\''+errMsgDiv+'\')" /></span>';
message +='</p>';
```

here i want to generate run time confirm dialog box, for that i need to pass `this` object in `yesOption` function.
but when i run this code, in that button, code is generated as  `Object` as a string, instead of `this` as current Object.
so any body please explain how to maintain state of that `Object(this Object)` at runtime.

Comment: please add significative code-snippet/JSFiddle to get help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
message='<p>Are you sure want to delete ?</p>';
message +='<p style=\'text-align:right;margin: 5px;\'>';                
message +='<span><input type=\'button\' value=\'Yes\' class=\'button\' /></span>';
message +='<span><input type=\'button\' value=\'No\' id=\'btnNo\' class=\'button\' /></span>';
message +='</p>';
var msgDOM = $(message);
var $this = this;
msgDom.find('button[value=Yes]').click(function() {
    yesOption($this, requestData, gridObject);
});
msgDom.find('button[value=No]').click(function() {
    noOption($this, requestData, gridObject);
});
```

You can't put DOM elements in strings, so you can't refer to them in inline Javascript like that. And you need to bind a local variable to `this` outside the handler functions, because `this` is set by jQuery to the element that was clicked on.

Comment: var msgDOM = $(message);
var $this = this;
msgDom.find('button[value=Yes]').click(function() {
    yesOption($this, requestData, gridObject);
});
msgDom.find('button[value=No]').click(function() {
    noOption($this, requestData, gridObject);
});   When this above function will call..? means who will call it.?

Comment: Sorry, it's hard to read code in comments, since there's no formatting. Is that the same code as my answer? You should put in whereever you put the code that was in your question. You'll have to adjust the code that adds it to the DOM -- use `.append()` instead of `.html()`.